# OLEDB .dbf Encoding

Tags: .net, character-encoding, oledb, dbf

I am reading a .DBF into a `DataSet` using a `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbDataAdapter`and am having an encoding issue.

The .DBFfile should be encoded as UTF-8.  In the .DBF, we use a special character (¬) as a delimiter for a particular field.  When I am reading in that field, the special character comes through as another character (¼).

My connection string is `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=PATH_TO_DIRECTORY;Extended Properties="dBASE IV;charset=65001"`.  I have tried a few different `charset` values such as `utf8` and `20127` based off the values I found at the MSDN [Code Page Identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) page, and other forum posts (where I saw someone putting `utf8` instead of a number).

I have also tried setting the  DataSet's `Locale` to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`.

I cannot change the data into another format because the .DBF is part of a shapefile, and I would prefer to not have to do a find/replace operation to fix the string either.  I can't leave the value as is because it will mess up a query against the same .DBF.

I haven't been able to correct this yet, nor have I been able to find suitable forum posts on `OleDB` encoding problems.  This looks to be a purely `OleDB` issue since other drivers (more GIS orientated) can read this in fine.  I would prefer to not change drivers either since the rest of the program utilizes `OleDB`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use UTF-8 encoding in connection string - it's just not supported. To be able to write UTF-8 to DBF, you should convert the source ANSI text to UTF-8 string, then write it. Vice versa for reading.